# Can be used an external exe file(also made by me) into an addon?

Tags: interface, add-on

I have a quick question for you today. 
If I want to make a plugin/addon and put it on sale that addon can have an external .exe program? And my actual addon to be just an interface in Blender which will let users interact with the core program(exe file)?

UPDATE:
If it's possible for a license point of view if I want to post that addon on sites like blendermarket.com for example
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? Do you mean if it is legal from a licensing point of view, or do you mean if it is technically feasible? Please edit your question and clarify, have in mind that we are not lawyers and this site is not adequate for legal matters

Comment: I think this has often been done before, at least for most external render engines

Comment: While addons must adhere to the GPL terms, it is possible for you to release an addon as GPL that is a bridge to a non-GPL application. You will want to provide both as separate packages to prevent license issues. An example would be the [renderman for blender](https://community.renderman.pixar.com/article/906/introduction-to-prman-for-blender.html) addon.